# Best Practices: Twilio Messaging Service per Tenant?

Tags: twilio, sms, auth0, password-less

When using Twilio to verify `sms` users within Auth0, is it a best-practice to create a messaging service per tenant? Or, can the same messaging service be used across development and production tenants?

My instinct is to create separate messaging services for each tenant, but there's a monthly cost associated with each number and numbers can't be used across services within Twilio. I'm wondering if there's a cost to sharing the same messaging service that I'm overlooking. Thanks for your help!

This question is also posted on the Auth0 Community board: https://community.auth0.com/t/best-practices-twilio-messaging-service-per-tenant/81471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content is templetized (the content cannot be created or modified by the tenants), like it would be for 2FA code generation, you can generate this code from a single number in a specific account. At this point in time, a verified Tollfree number is the best number type outside a shortcode to use.

Twilio Verify provides such an approach.

Although these blog posts are focused on Twilio Verify, the same information is useful for any 2FA use case.

Migrate from Programmable Messaging to Verify
https://www.twilio.com/blog/migrate-programmable-sms-to-verify

Build a carrier block list with Twilio Lookup
https://www.twilio.com/blog/carrier-block-list-lookup-fraud-prevention

Build an allow list to filter sign ups by country with Twilio Lookup
https://www.twilio.com/blog/allow-list-country-code-lookup

Best practices for phone number validation during new user enrollment

- Build retry buffers into verification workflows
  https://www.twilio.com/blog/best-practices-phone-number-validation-user-enrollment

Best practices for managing retry logic with SMS 2FA
https://www.twilio.com/blog/best-practices-retry-logic-sms-2fa

How to Validate Phone Number Input in HTML and JavaScript
https://www.twilio.com/blog/validate-phone-number-input

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, Alan. We received some feedback from Auth0 on this as well. They had two thoughts: 
1) They suggested that throttling might be an issue if multiple tenants had sufficient volume.
2) They suggested that interpreting the logs might be more difficult if we couldn't partition by tenant/number. I haven't looked into logs at all on Twilio. Do you think this is a valid concern?

Comment: Hi Zane. Throttling for 2FA really depends on what you think the high water mark will be (requests per second) to sending those requests and the number type. We do have High Throughput TollFree (HTTF) if you need a throughput higher then 3 Message Segments Per Second (MSPS) - recommended a verified Toll Free. For US Long Codes, the throughput is dictated by your brand Trust Score or for Starter Campaigns set throughput values. You can request statusCallbacks, to get the disposition of a 2FA to the endpoint (TF provide to the endpoint DLR vs to the carrier which 10DLC offers).